# Como pesquisar trecho de palavra dentro do XML usando PHP

Tags: php, xml

Utilizo esse código que é para retornar dados referente a cada nome pesquisado, porém a consulta só funciona se eu digitar um nome de forma identica, queria digitar "Smartphone" e ele me retornar todas as pesquisas que tenham essa alavra no titulo.
Podem me ajudar?

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" >
Nome <input type="text" name="nome" value="" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {   
   $xml = simplexml_load_file('https://actionpay.net/br-pt/couponFeed/xmlFilter/id:6607');
    $erro = 0;
    foreach ($xml->promotion AS $val) {
        if ($val->title == $_POST['nome']) {
            echo "<div class='single-product'>
                           <div class='product-f-image'>

                              <div class='product-hover'>
                                 <a href='$val->offer_link' class='add-to-cart-link' target='_blank'><img src='$val->logo' alt=''>$val->title</a>
                              </div>
                           </div>

                           <div class='product-carousel-price'>
                              <del></del>  
                           </div>
                        </div>";
            $erro++;
        }
    }
    if ($erro == 0) {
        echo "nenhum valor encontrado";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar a função nativa **strpos**:

```
if (strpos($val->title, $_POST['nome']) !== false) {
   [seu codigo]
}
```

> strpos
>
> (PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7)
>
> strpos — Encontra a posição da primeira ocorrência de uma string

Ela vai procurar pela palavra dentro da string, e caso não encontre nada retorna false. Então qualquer resultado diferente de false significa que encontrou algum resultado.

Comment: Perfeito, muito obrigado irmão.

Comment: @Nogueira se funcionou marca a resposta como certa para ajudar quem tiver com a mesma dúvida. Vlw